# Recover shift-deleted .hg or .git folder and its content in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I've tried using Recuva, Undelete Plus, and some other tools. But it seems these tools are unable to find the content stored in .hg or .git folder, I can only recover .hgignore or .gitignore files. Does this have anything to do with NTFS? Is there any way to recover these files? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Usually you can only recover files, not folders, due to the differences in how they are stored. For git, search for files with filenames like `97e976b99de7a2e22e83ba619a019571ce913a` or `pack-75910f9afc31862111442119c47ca55b9ec9769d.pack`, those contain the actual data.